# How can I regenerate current userClaims and roles manually in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using asp.net identity as my security framework, and I'm aware of `regenerateIdentity` in my `app.UseCookieAuthentication`.

I'm adding some claims to my user e.g. fullname, email that might be updated through profile page, how can I update current user claims when updating user profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i used,
signout and signin again with this user using below method

```
private async Task SignInAsync(User user, bool isPersistent)
{
   AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
   var identity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager);
   AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```